# javascript summing up array

Tags: javascript

I`m trying to sum the values of the elements in an array using javascript, this is my script.

```
function sumAll()
{
    var totalOverheads = 0;
    var overheads = new Array();
    overheads = document.getElementsByName('overhead');
    for(i=0;i<overheads.length;i++)
        if(!isNaN(overheads[i].value) || overheads[i].value != null || overheads[i].value != "" || overheads[i].value != '' || overheads[i].value != NULL)
            alert(overheads[i].value);
            //totalOverheads = parseInt(totalOverheads) + parseInt(overheads[i].value);
    alert(totalOverheads);
}
```

for now, in the if condition inside the for loop, I`m displaying the value of the item in an alert, yet it`s not working correctly, it just displays all the items even if the item is not a number, how can I perform an operation if the input is only a number?

Comment: `NULL` is the same as `null` - you don't need to compare against it twice.

Comment: @nickf: ok, why is giving me all the values even if I don`t type in any!

Comment: getElementsByName returns an array of objects. you need an outer loop to loop through those and an inner to loop through the items in each array.

Comment: @josh.trow: how can I accomplish this?

Comment: you can shorten the if() to `if (overheads[i].value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByName` returns a NodeList. Not sure if that was the problem, but anyway:

```
var totalOverheads = 0;
var overheads = document.getElementsByName('overhead');
var n;
var i; // <<--- don't forget to initialise i
for (i = 0; i < overheads.length; ++i) {
    n = parseInt(overheads.item(i).value, 10);
    if (!isNaN(n)) {
        totalOverheads += n;
    }
}
alert(totalOverheads);
```

*Also, please use brackets!*

Comment: if I`m using floats, shall I use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`??

Comment: @sikas Yep. It would work the same (but you know, with floats). I only used parseInt because it's used in the OP.